# WPMU function get_blog_details, last_updated/registered and formatting time and date string

Tags: multisite, blog-id

Within my multisite installation I can get the registered and last updated time strings for a sub blog through get_blog_details and the blog ID:

```
echo get_blog_details($blog_ID)->registered
```

Ok, how do I format the resulting time string:

```
2011-09-28 00:20:34
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$time = get_blog_details($blog_ID)->registered;
$unix_time = strtotime($time);

$my_time_format = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $time);  // eg. 2011-09-28 00:20:34
$diff_format = human_time_diff($time);          // eg. 2 days
```

See [date()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and replace `Y-m-d H:i:s` with the format you want